# The type arguments for method… cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'am facing a problem when I try to create Server-side Datatable in my Asp.Net MVC 
The code looks as following:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CustomerList()
        {
            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" +
            Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int totalRecords = 0;

            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var resultData = (from cust in db.Customers
                                      //orderby sortColumn
                                  select cust);



                //Sorting
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
                {
                    resultData = resultData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir); // Here is failing (OrderBy)
                }
                totalRecords = resultData.Count();
                var data = resultData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                return Json(new
                {
                    draw = draw,
                    recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
                    recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                    data = data
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

The issue is in this line:

```
resultData = resultData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
```

The error:

```
CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Queryable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

Thank you guys in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved.. I added the namespace: using System.Linq.Dynamic; and added Tolist() in the is in the issue  line:

Answer (score 0):

First fall You need install NuGet Package Manager (Go to project folder and right click find it NuGet Package Manager) after that install it

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core
```

this package is used for order data as we order in SQL query.

And then Declare name on the top namespace

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
```